# Better Choice between React Native and Flutter(Dart)

Tags: react-native, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I will like to start mobile app development, but don't know which is a better choice between flutter and react native.

I would like some suggestions based on which is easier to learn and also more flexible with a better community and which one I can use to get a lot of work in which the development process is faster.

Thanks
Oyero H.O

Comment: You can ask for all the tips and suggestions in the world, but the only way to know for sure is to try them both and see which one you like more.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all you need to describe  what knowledge area you have.. if you are already javascript developer the react-native will be so easy for you to lean and fast development you will deliver..
if you are did not have any big development experience in JS i will recommended Flutter
please read more about it here

https://medium.com/flutter-community/why-flutter-has-become-the-best-choice-to-develop-a-startup-mobile-app-in-2020-5785ea153b13

Comment: I have some experinece in javascript as well as reactjs